# How to add validation for making sure that model prop is URL and it can be accessed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have right now a model called `Blog` that has a URL prop, and I would like to add a validation to check if it's a URL and if can be accessed.

I've came up with the former validation:

```
class UrlValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    return if value.blank?
    begin
      uri = URI.parse(value)
      resp = uri.kind_of?(URI::HTTP)
    rescue URI::InvalidURIError
      resp = false
    end
    unless resp == true
      record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "is not an url")
    end
  end
end
```

and in my model:

```
class Blog < ApplicationRecord
  validates :url, presence: true, url: true
end
```

Now I would like your help with the later validation.

Comment: Would this URL be inside your application, or it could be from anywhere?

In the first case you could check if that url matches any rails route, otherwise you'd need to make a request to the url to verify if it's up or not by checking the http status.

Also, are you using any library for making http requests or do you want to do it with the standard ruby library?

Comment: It could be from anywhere, that's why I need to validate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this, although I don't know if making an http request each time you validate a model's a good practice.

```
require 'net/http'

class UrlAvailabilityValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    return if value.blank?
    begin

    url = URI.parse value 

    response = Net::HTTP.get_response(url)
    is_http_success = response.kind_of? Net::HTTPSuccess

    rescue URI::InvalidURIError
      is_http_success = false
    end

    is_http_success or record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "is not available")
    end
  end
end
```